# Joining two views on id AND date not working

Tags: sql

**Situation thus far**

I have two tables `sales_orders` and `purchase_orders` which contain `id`, `company_id` and `inserted_at` each.

I created two views `sales_orders_view` and `purchase_orders_view` which truncate the timestamp to that week's monday (using the `date_trunc` function) and count the orders entered by each company. So my `sales_order_view` and `purchase_order_view` look like this:

[image: example dataset from sales_orders_view]
[image: example dataset from purchase_orders_view]

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I am trying to join the two views to create a data set which looks as follows:

[image: desired result]

This is what I am doing:

```sql
SELECT
    so.company_id,
    so.week_of,
    so.sales_orders,
    po.purchase_orders
FROM
    sales_orders_view so
INNER JOIN
    purchases_orders_view po
    ON so.company_id = po.company_id
GROUP BY
    so.company_id,
    so.week_of,
    sales_orders,
    purchase_orders
```

The numbers I get back as a result are completely out of whack and I can't figure out for the life of me what I am doing wrong.

Would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: you should be `join`ing on `week_of` column too.

Comment: You're not joining on the date column

Comment: I tried that too, didn't change the results

Comment: @Kopty How could adding extra join condition didn't change the result?  It will definitely change the result.

Comment: Eric You are correct. I just tried @Gordon Linoff's answer from below and it worked. The mistake I was making was that I was doing grouping which was messing everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No aggregation is needed.  Just include the week in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT so.company_id, so.week_of, so.sales_orders,
       po.purchase_orders
FROM sales_orders_view so INNER JOIN
      purchases_orders_view po
      ON so.company_id = po.company_id AND so.week_of = po.week_of;
```

Note:  This only returns weeks that are in *both* tables for a given company.  If you want all weeks where there are no matches, then you need an outer join of some sort.